# Influência na região escolhida na AWS em performance

Tags: desempenho, amazon-aws, deploy

Logicamente, comparando duas infraestruturas semelhantes, espera-se que a mais perto do `request` do usuário responda mais rapidamente.

Para aplicações web na AWS em geral (não sendo real time), a diferença entre regiões é significativa?

Pergunto porque gostaria de usar o CloudFoundry para fazer deploy dos meus apps, mas só vejo ele disponível via região US-East. Tenho medo da minha aplicação ficar lenta porque ela seria restrita a usuários do Brasil.

Answer (score 0):

Depende muito de sua aplicação, em todo caso, segue aqui alguns recursos para avaliar melhor:

- Voce pode usar o http://cloudping.info para estimar a latência da sua rede local até as regiões da AWS.
- Além da latência, considere também que o preço e disponibilidade dos serviços é diferente por região.
- Com o Amazon CloudFront pode se obter o melhor preço e a melhor latência. Considere usar a região americana e os pontos de presença globais para distribuição de conteúdo.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta mas queria algo mais compreensivo sobre a influência da latência no desempenho da aplicação. É somente adicionar a latência ao tempo de resposta de todo request? Vezes dois porque o request tem que ir ao usuário e voltar ao servidor?

Comment: Na verdade é um pouco mais complicado, porque depende muito da aplicação e como ela se comporta. A quantidade de requisições, e a distribuição dos tempos de resposta, influencia muito. Se quer algo mais aprofundado, recomendo o livro e palestras do Brendan Gregg